# Proving an ideal is prime and calculating dimension of the corresponding quotient ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, krull-dimension

I was asked the following question during my oral exam (seminar course on commutative algebra), but I couldn't answer. I would like to learn how to solve such problems.

> Prove/disprove that $I = \langle X^2+Y^2-Z^2+XY\rangle$ is a prime ideal in $R = k[X,Y,Z]$, where $k$ is a field. Also, prove that the Krull dimension of the quotient ring $R/I$ is $1$.

This course has been very advance for me (most of Atiyah-MacDonald was covered), and I am a slow learner. Hence a detailed discussion about such problems will be appreciated.

**Edit:** based on the comments of [MooS](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/211913/moos) and [Bernard](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/202857/bernard) it's clear that I remembered the second part of the problem wrongly. It should be:

> Prove that the Krull dimension of the quotient ring $R/I$ is $2$, or
>   equivalently that $\:\operatorname{Proj}R/I$ has dimension 1.

Comment: For the first question, just check $X^2+Y^2-Z^2+XY$ cannot be factored as the product of two linear forms  $\;(aX+bY+cZ)(a'X+b'Y+c'Z)$.

Comment: The second assertion is wrong. The quotient of $k[x,y,z]$ by a non-zero principal ideal is always of dimension two.

Comment: @Bernard done. Thanks!

Comment: @MooS can you please give a proof of your assertion or give me a link where I can find a proof. Thank you.

Comment: This is called Krull's Principal ideal theorem.

Comment: @MooS: Maybe  it is meant that $\:\operatorname{Proj}R/I$ has dimension $1$.

Comment: @Bernard I don't think so, since it is explicitly called *Krull dimension of the quotient ring*. Another explaination could be that there is a comma instead of a plus or minus in the definition of the ideal. The ideal would be not prime then, but the dimension of the quotient would be one.

Comment: @MooS thanks. I think I heard/remembered it wrongly since I was in panicking state (problems given to you to be solved on the spot on the blackboard).

Comment: @Bernard maybe the instructor tried to clarify it the way you wrote, and I mixed the two notions (dimension of affine and projective variety).

Comment: @MooS as per Wikipedia, the statement of the Krull's principal ideal theorem is: " If R is a Noetherian ring and I is a principal, proper ideal of R, then I has height at most one. " And  the Krull dimension of a ring is the supremum of the heights of all maximal ideals, or those of all prime ideals. Hence shouldn't the Krull dimension be 1?